# Wordpress - woocommerce - adding to cart, cart item quantity not updating

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am changing the input_value for the product quantity input with woocommerce_quantity_input().

It dose what I want, but only if I do a hard reloade of the browser.

If I just add the product to the cart and reloade the cart the quantity wont update.

Maybe its cached, and if so. Can I clear it? Or can I simulate a hard reset?

```
$product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
    'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
    'input_value'  => $sInputValue,
    'max_value'    => $aProductMaxData[0]->product_max_cap,
    'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
), $_product, false );
```

This is the hook I'm using

```
woocommerce_cart_item_quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you tring to update quantity using Ajax, would you like to share your site link to look.

Comment: No I am not using ajax, its on localhost